# Approximation of binomial

Tags: approximation, fractions, binomial-theorem

I have the following quantity:

$$\frac{gp+1-(gp+1)^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{gp}$$

I have the value of $g$ and $x$ but I do not have the value of $p$. Another issue  is that $gp$ is greater than $1$. Any suggestions how to approximate the above so I could get rid of $p$?

Comment: Are you meaning that in $y=\frac{gp+1-(gp+1)^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{gp}$ you know $g$, $x$ and $y$ and that you look for $p$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No. I know $g$ and $x$, only. I look for $p$ and $y$.